# access point wifi + linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have been succesful creating a wifi access point in linux. I have used hostapd and a dhcp server. I have also used a static address using the command: `ifconfig wlan0 10.10.0.1`. I would like to use the /etc/network/interfaces file to put a static address instead of using the command above. I have writen:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface wlan0 inet static
address 10.10.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

After restarting the service networking the access point doesn't work. So could I use the file interfaces instead of the ifconfig command? and how? because my interfaces file doesn't work....thanks

Comment: It seems all is correct. Sorry for the question. I did `service networking restart` and the access point failed. But after switching off/on the linux device, the access point works correctly